# Simplified Caesars Cipher

Tags: javascript, caesar-cipher, ecmascript-6

I'm studying functional programming, and I have the following problem to solve. It's an simplified version of Caesars Cipher:

- You need to write a function, which will take string encoded with Caesar cipher as a parameter and decode it.
- The one used here is ROT13 where the value of the letter is shifted by 13 places. e.g. 'A' ↔ 'N', 'T' ↔ 'G'.
- You have to shift it back 13 positions, such that 'N' ↔ 'A'.

I made the following implementation:

```
const head = (str) => str[0];
const tail = (str) => str.slice(1);
const code = (str) => str.charCodeAt(0);

const rot13 = (str) => str ? (code(str) < 65 || code(str) > 90) ? head(str).concat(rot13(tail(str))) : String.fromCharCode((((code(str) - 65)) + 13) % 26 + 65).concat(rot13(tail(str))) : '';
```

It works fine, I only want to know if there is performance issues, and what can I do to improve my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the performance, but readability-wise, cramming that double-nested ternary on a single line of code isn't, well, ideal.

Give it some [vertical] air:

```
const rot13 = (str) => str 
   ? (code(str) < 65 || code(str) > 90) 
       ? head(str).concat(rot13(tail(str))) 
       : String.fromCharCode((((code(str) - 65)) + 13) % 26 + 65).concat(rot13(tail(str))) 
   : '';
```

Ah, already better.

I'm no [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) expert, but being all inline, it probably performs better than if you further improved readability by introducing a function for each of the two outcomes of the inner condition... on the other hand, that could just as well be *premature optimization* - so I'd still go for readability and extract the logic into its own function.

Comment: I agree that my code is not that readable. I solved a little of it by splitting the functions (imagine each `code(str)` as `str.charCodeAt(0)`), but as Ecmascript does not have pattern matching, there's no much to do. Thanks.

Comment: @I'lladdcommentstomorrow The functionality is in it's own function itself. I only made a sweet syntax of it, but the problem-solving logic is all in one function.

Comment: @Mat'sMug About your edit, have a look at ES6 arrow function, this will answer your question. The function is there, even with no `function` keyword being used.

Comment: I'll vote your question until someone gives an answer with more info.